# Python pip install exception matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Operational System: OSX 10.11.3.

I've installed Python: 2.7.10 and 3.4.2.

executed command: pip install matplotlib

**pip instalation log**

> pip install matplotlib Downloading/unpacking matplotlib   Downloading
>   matplotlib-1.5.1.tar.gz (54.0MB): 54.0MB downloaded   Running setup.py
>   (path:/private/var/folders/x1/prmwnk854tj25kslmzb10l5h0000gn/T/pip_build_calebebrim/matplotlib/setup.py)
>   egg_info for package matplotlib
>       ============================================================================
>       Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
>
> ```
> BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
>             matplotlib: yes [1.5.1]
>                 python: yes [2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:06:28)  [GCC
>                         4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)]]
>               platform: yes [darwin]
>
> REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
>                  numpy: yes [version 1.10.4]
>               dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
>                         axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
>                         install it after matplotlib.]
>                   pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
>                         it after matplotlib.]
>                 cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
>                         install it after matplotlib.]
>                tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.3]
>              pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
>                         mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
>                         install it after matplotlib.]
>                 libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
>                         be found. Using local copy.]
>               freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
>                         could not be found.  You may need to install the
>                         development package.]
>                    png: yes [version 1.5.23]
>                  qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
>                         found. Using local copy.]
>
> OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
>            sample_data: yes [installing]
>               toolkits: yes [installing]
>                  tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
>                         matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
>                         your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
>                         required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
>                         install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
>                         the test suite]
>         toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
>                         matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
>                         your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
>                         required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
>                         install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
>                         the test suite]
>
> OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
>                 macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
>                 qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
>                 qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
>                gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
>              gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
>                 gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
>                  tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]
>                  wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
>                    gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
>                    agg: yes [installing]
>                  cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
>              windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
>
> OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
>                 dvipng: no
>            ghostscript: yes [version 9.10]
>                  latex: no
>                pdftops: no
>
> OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
>                   dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
>
> ============================================================================
>                         * The following required packages can not be built:
>                         * freetype
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> ============================================================================
> ```
>
> Edit setup.cfg to change the build options
>
> BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
>
> ```
>         matplotlib: yes [1.5.1]
>
>             python: yes [2.7.8 (default, Oct 19 2014, 16:06:28)  [GCC
>
>                     4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)]]
>
>           platform: yes [darwin]
> ```
>
> REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
>
> ```
>              numpy: yes [version 1.10.4]
>
>           dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
>
>                     axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
>
>                     install it after matplotlib.]
>
>               pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip will attempt to install
>
>                     it after matplotlib.]
>
>             cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
>
>                     install it after matplotlib.]
>
>            tornado: yes [using tornado version 4.3]
>
>          pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
>
>                     mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
>
>                     install it after matplotlib.]
>
>             libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
>
>                     be found. Using local copy.]
>
>           freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
>
>                     could not be found.  You may need to install the
>
>                     development package.]
>
>                png: yes [version 1.5.23]
>
>              qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
>
>                     found. Using local copy.]
> ```
>
> OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
>
> ```
>        sample_data: yes [installing]
>
>           toolkits: yes [installing]
>
>              tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
>
>                     matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
>
>                     your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
>
>                     required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
>
>                     install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
>
>                     the test suite]
>
>     toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
>
>                     matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
>
>                     your preferred tool to run the test suite / mock is
>
>                     required to run the matplotlib test suite. Please
>
>                     install it with pip or your preferred tool to run
>
>                     the test suite]
> ```
>
> OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
>
> ```
>             macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
>
>             qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
>
>             qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
>
>            gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
>
>          gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
>
>             gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
>
>              tkagg: yes [installing, version 81008]
>
>              wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
>
>                gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
>
>                agg: yes [installing]
>
>              cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
>
>          windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]
> ```
>
> OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
>
> ```
>             dvipng: no
>
>        ghostscript: yes [version 9.10]
>
>              latex: no
>
>            pdftops: no
> ```
>
> OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
>
> ```
>               dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]
> ```
>
> ============================================================================
>
> ```
>                     * The following required packages can not be built:
>
>                     * freetype
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Removing temporary dir
>       /private/var/folders/x1/prmwnk854tj25kslmzb10l5h0000gn/T/pip_build_calebebrim...
>       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>       /private/var/folders/x1/prmwnk854tj25kslmzb10l5h0000gn/T/pip_build_calebebrim/matplotlib
>       Exception information: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>       "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>       line 122, in main
>           status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>       line 278, in run
>           requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>       "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>       line 1229, in prepare_files
>           req_to_install.run_egg_info()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>       line 325, in run_egg_info
>           command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py",
>       line 697, in call_subprocess
>           % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>       /private/var/folders/x1/prmwnk854tj25kslmzb10l5h0000gn/T/pip_build_calebebrim/matplotlib

And this one is for: sudo pip install matplotlib

> Cleaning up...   Removing temporary dir /private/tmp/pip_build_root...
>   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib Exception information:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",
>   line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py",
>   line 278, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>   line 1229, in prepare_files
>       req_to_install.run_egg_info()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py",
>   line 325, in run_egg_info
>       command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py",
>   line 697, in call_subprocess
>       % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/tmp/pip_build_root/matplotlib

What should I do?

I found this: 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3029/
it say's that executing sudo apt-get pkg-config or, on osx, brew install pkg-config should fix everything.

but executing the brew install pkgconfig I got this:

> Warning: pkg-config-0.28 already installed

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @Pythogen I'm Using OSX

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `sudo` when you use `pip` on a Mac, otherwise `pip` can't access the folders it needs to with normal privileges. So, put `sudo` before your command:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

You'll also need to type in your administrator password, but then it'll install.

Comment: Don't need `sudo` for `/usr/local` directory

Answer (score 1):

I resolve my problems.

what I did?

remove all MACPOrts, brew.

install homebrew agan.

all permissions was reset.

I've use brew install for everything.

than..
Done.